# Laravel insert empty value Postgress error

Tags: postgresql, orm, pdo, laravel, insert

When creating elements in Laravel 4 using the ORM like so:

```
FigureModel::create( array( 'numericFieldOne'=>1, 'numericFieldTwo'=> null ) );
FigureModel::create( array( 'numericFieldOne'=>1, 'numericFieldTwo'=> '' ) );
```

In mysql all is well and all the items are perfect inserterd, no problem so far:
[image]

But in postgress, it tries to insert empty values without a quote making postress crash. Like so:

[image]

What to do?? Does anyone have an idea about how to tackle this problem? Thanks!!

( and custom setters for each element validating it to be a number or null is not an option )

Comment: Dear Richard, 
Im sorry that my screenshots have afended you, ill do it the way you suggested from now on. But to expect im trying to make everyone's life harder is a bit of a stretch dont you think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Laravel's debug screen cheats you: if the query really was that, the postgres error would be `syntax error at or near ","` with SQL state `42601`

The problem is, postgres does not accept `''` (the empty string) as a valid representation for an integer.

Use one of `0`, `'0'`, like:

```
FigureModel::create(array('worldwideoffices' => 1, 'worldwideemployees' => 0));
FigureModel::create(array('worldwideoffices' => 1, 'worldwideemployees' => '0'));
```

But preferably use `null` if it makes more sense.

Note: if you insert data from another source, just use casting to integer in php:

```
FigureModel::create(array(
    'worldwideoffices'   => (int) $offices,
    'worldwideemployees' => (int) $employees,
));
```

Comment: I don't really see a problem with his first command `FigureModel::create( array( 'worldwideoffices'=>1, 'worldwideemployees'=> null ) );` and Laravel/Postgres should accept null if the column is nullable.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro that's why i wrote *But preferably use null if it makes more sense* - but there are cases, when it makes a difference (f.ex. `null` means N/A - not meaningful, but `0` means meaningful, but zero)

Answer (score 1):

@pozs Thanks! since you pointed out that the correct error should be a 42601 im once again confidant that the prostgress adapter for this orm is sound.

**The solution:**
In my case i just have to create setter functions for all the numeric null values in the database something like this

```
public function setNumericFieldAttribute($var){
    $this->attributes['numericField'] = empty($var) ? null : $var;
}
```

This way the value is always null or a value

Thanks!!